# In python 3.7, how do I check that x=typing.List[str] is "of" typing.List?

Tags: typing, python-3.7

I'm storing type information in a variable `x`:

```
x = typing.List[str]
```

Later, this `x` is passed together with `x_value` and I want to switch logic depending on whether `x` *is of* `typing.List`. I'm aware that `typing` shouldn't be used together with `isinstance` and `issubclass` hence I am saying *is of*. Is there any standard, future proof (and Python 3.6 proof) way of doing this `issubtype`?

```
import sys
from typing import List


def issubtype(sub_type, parent_type):
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 7):
        if not hasattr(sub_type, '__origin__') or not hasattr(parent_type, '__origin__'):
            return False

        if sub_type.__origin__ != parent_type.__origin__:
            return False

        if isinstance(parent_type.__args__[0], type):
            return sub_type.__args__ == parent_type.__args__

        return True

    else:
        if not hasattr(sub_type, '__extra__') or not hasattr(parent_type, '__extra__'):
            return False

        if sub_type.__extra__ != parent_type.__extra__:
            return False

        if not parent_type.__args__ or parent_type.__args__ == sub_type.__args__:
            return True

    return False


assert issubtype(List[str], List[str])
assert issubtype(List[str], List)
assert issubtype(List[int], List[int])
assert not issubtype(List[int], List[str])
```

When trying to implement this I realise that any good solution would have to recursively check args (which my attempt doesn't do, but for me just knowing if a thing is a list is enough).

Comment: This isn't a really great answer, but maybe you could try using the [typing_inspect](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect) library in some way -- or at least look at the source code for inspiration. Similarly, maybe try looking at runtime type validators like [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard).

Comment: I would also consider just converting the type into a string and parsing it. Type hints will be automatically stored as strings in future Python versions anyways (and *will* be stored as strings if you add a `from __future__ import annotations` import in any Python 3.7+ codebase), so the "parse from scratch" approach might legitimately be the most future-proof way of doing it. You could maybe even invoke mypy as a library -- the [API is very minimal](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending_mypy.html#integrating-mypy-into-another-python-application), but it's one starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Michael0x2a - didn't know about typing_inspect and about moving to strings. Looks like something I could use.